# Predicting values using trained MNB Classifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, classification, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to train a model for sentiment analysis and below is my trained Multinomial Naive Bayes Classifier returning an accuracy of 84%.

I have been unable to figure out how to use the trained model to predict the sentiment of a sentence. For example, I now want to use the trained model to predict the sentiment of the phrase "I hate you".

I am new to this area and any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the dataset and what is semantic of individual dictionaries, but you are training your model on a dataset which has form as follows:

`[[{"word":True, "word2": False}, 'neg'], [{"word":True, "word2": False}, 'pos']]`

- That means your input is in form of a dictionary, and output in form of `'neg'` label. If you want to predict you need to input a dictionary in a form:

`{"I": True, "Hate": False, "you": True}`.

- Then:

`MNB_classifier.classify({"love": True})`

`>> 'neg'`

or 
`MNB_classifier.classify_many([{"love": True}])`

`>> ['neg']`